# Does MJML work with Oultook.com and Outlook 2016?

Tags: html, email, frameworks, html-email, mjml

Does MJML work with `Oultook.com` and `Outlook 2016`? If not are there any other email template frameworks that do work with `Oultook.com` and `Outlook 2016`?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you realize trying it out yourself would have taken less time than asking a question on stackoverflow and waiting for an answer?

Comment: @NicolasGarnier, contrargument will prove that you are wrong: if I have an Android phone only and do not have a laptop with me it would take a significant amount of time to find the needed soft, install it and figure out how it works.

Comment: @NicolasGarnier, also, please, pay attention that it is impossible for anyone to prove what I am asking (merely because I did not find the info about this in documentation or merely because in my Outlook the mjml does not work does not mean that it does not work with Outlook, I could have just made a mistake). So, a person with the experience in the field is needed to answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: Making an account on Outlook.com is pretty quick but your point about potential mistakes makes sense. Speaking of which, a common mistake is to use a method of sending that will break the HTML (such as pasting the HTML in an email client directly). A good way to test is to send via https://putsmail.com/ which is free and doesn't alter the HTML (do NOT check "Move my CSS inline when I click Send Email" though, it would break the responsiveness and MJML already inlines CSS).

Comment: @NicolasGarnier, you can send emails using the mjml [app](https://mjmlio.github.io/mjml-app/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it works out of the box for all email clients.

There is just a trick for Outlook.com as it doesn't support media queries: the email will appear in the mobile layout by default. You can force the desktop layout for Outlook.com with `<mjml owa="desktop">`